# pandas function to find index of the first future instance where column is less than each row's value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Stack Overflow, and I just have a question about solving a problem in pandas. I am looking to create a function that returns the index of the first future instance where a column is less than each row's value for that column.

For example, consider the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, -1, -2, -3]}, index = np.arange(0,9))
df
```

| Index | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | -1 |
| 7 | -2 |
| 8 | -3 |

I am looking for the output:

| Index | F(Val) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 8 | NaN |

Or the series/array equivalent of F(Val).

I've been able to solve this quite easily using for loops, but obviously this is extremely slow on the large dataset I am working with an not a very elegant or optimal solution. My hope is that the solution is an efficient pandas function that employs vectorization.

Also, as a bonus question (if anyone can assist), how might the maximum value between each row's index and the F(Val) index be computed using vectorization? The output should look like:

| Index | G(Val) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | -1 |
| 7 | -2 |
| 8 | NaN |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
grp = df['Val'].lt(df['Val'].shift()).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
df['F(Val)'] = df.groupby(grp).transform(lambda x: x.index[-1]).shift(-1)
print(df)

# Output
   Val  F(Val)
0    1     4.0
1    2     4.0
2    3     4.0
3    4     4.0
4    0     6.0
5    1     6.0
6   -1     7.0
7   -2     8.0
8   -3     NaN
```

Comment: Actually is this correct? I have some doubts depending on the exact logic, what if the input was `df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, -2, -1, -2, -3]}, index = np.arange(0,9))`? What should be the first `F(Val)`? `5` or `4`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting and the lower triangle:

```
a = df['Val'].to_numpy()
m = np.tril(a[:,None]<=a, k=-1)
df['F(Val)'] = np.where(m.any(0), m.argmax(0), np.nan)
```

Same logic with `expanding`:

```
df['F(Val)'] = (df.loc[::-1, 'Val'].expanding()
                  .apply(lambda x: s.idxmax() if len(s:=(x.iloc[-2::-1]<=x.iloc[-1]))
                         else np.nan)
               )
```

Output (with a difference to the provided one):

```
   Val  F(Val)
0    1     5.0  # here the next is 5
1    2     4.0
2    3     4.0
3    4     4.0
4    2     5.0
5   -2     7.0
6   -1     7.0
7   -2     8.0
8   -3     NaN
```